# Finding events bound on non-existent elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm planning to mercilessly re-factoring a lot of front-end code I have.  Code has been added willy-nilly, features have been completely rewritten, and I know I've got a lot of events that are set up to listen on elements that don't exist.

Is there a way of finding code that attaches jQuery events to non-existent elements?  Was hoping to find events that aren't used anymore without going through all the code manually.

Comment: What do you mean "attaches events to non-existent elements"; `null.addEventListener` - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Comment: @PaulS. `$('#non-existant-element').on()`, `$('#non-existant-element').click()`, etc.

Comment: I guess the only events I need to check are the jQuery events, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible debugging step is to override the `on` method with a debug version as shown below. It will list event registration attempts where the element set is empty and the trace for locating the code.

```
(function(){
    var old = $.fn.each;
    $.fn.each = function(){
        if(this.length == 0){
            console.debug('non-selector', this.selector)
            console.trace()
        }
        return old.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bfMzG/)

Comment: [This is actually pretty genius!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBh895KdXAU&noredirect=1)

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica hopefully from here you will be able to manage!!